# Highcharts - On and Off over Time

Tags: django, highcharts

This hopefully is an easy questions.

I'm using Highcharts through chartit in Django and can get most of my graphs to work (temp and time). I'm now trying to graph the values ON and OFF over time. It seems that highcharts can't interpret the strings in the Y Axis (ON and OFF). Is there a way to get it to use those values?

I've tried using something like this in the chart_option section.

```
'yAxis': {
                'categories': ['ON', 'OFF'], 
                 'title': {'text': 'Status'}}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the format of your data? Could you for example replace ON/OFF with 0/1?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. The data is saved in to MySQL by another program and goes in as ON and OFF and that would be very difficult to change. Thanks for the thought though.

Answer (score 1):

Point's `y` coordinate in series' data must be a number, so you would have to process your data to have it in required format. It would be for the best to do this server side and provide proper data for JS, but if that is not possible then you could process data in JS.

```
$(function() {
  var data = ['ON', 'OFF', 'OFF', 'ON'],
    processedData = [];
  Highcharts.each(data, function(point) {
    processedData.push(point === 'ON' ? 1 : 0);
  });

  $('#container').highcharts({
    'yAxis': {
      'categories': ['ON', 'OFF'],
      'title': {
        'text': 'Status'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: processedData
    }]
  });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ptu6qhjy/

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I will give it a go. I'm using Chartit for Django so I'll need to try and translate this in to their slightly strange syntax. Thanks!